# Android hide and display numberPicker

Tags: android, show-hide, numberpicker

I am trying to get a the `NumberPicker` to appear when I click into an editable text box so that the user can use the `NumberPicker` to select a value instead of from the keyboard.

At the moment all I have is:

```
 public void NumberPicker()
 {
     NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker)findViewById(R.id.np1);
     np.setMaxValue(300);
     np.setMinValue(0);
     np.setValue(0);
     np.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Number selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
     });
  }
```

Layout

```
 <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/np1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: From what it sounds like, you should have your listener on your edit text. Not numberpicker. 
On click, make the number picker appear in some kind of popup alert dialog. Rather than your current layout. Plus it stands to reason that if you dont want them to edit it directly, use `TextView` instead of `EditText`.

Comment: Just use np.setVisibility(View.GONE); and np.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); to show and hide your NumberPicker

Answer (score 0):

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pid_input"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="IPD"
            android:inputType="numberSigned" />

        <NumberPicker
            android:id="@+id/pid_inputPicker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal"
            android:visibility="gone" />
```

and the code

```
    String[] pidArray = {"54","56","58","60","62","64","66","68","70","72","74"};     

    pidInputPicker.setMinValue(0);
    pidInputPicker.setMaxValue(pidArray.length-1);
    pidInputPicker.setDisplayedValues(pidArray);
    pidInputPicker.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    /* initially */
    pidInputPicker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pidInput.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    pidInput.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pidInputPicker.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    pidInputPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String selected = pidArray[pidInputPicker.getValue()];
            pidInput.setText(selected);
            pidInputPicker.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
   }
```